# Strongloop Loopback: Filter by id of related Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a Strongloop Loopback Node.js project with some models and relations.

**The problem at hand**

My problem relates how to query only those `Media` instances that have a relation to a certain `Tag` id, using the Angular SDK - *while* **not** querying `Tags.media` (which return `Tag` instances), but instead making a query somehow that returns plain `Media` instances.

Please read below for specific information..

**Spec**

Basically, I have a Model `Media` which has many 'tags' (model `Tag`). Think of a image file (`Media`) having various EXIF tags (`Tag`). Here is the relation spec (this all works as expected):

Media (media.json):

```
{
  "name": "media",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "tag"
    }
}
```

Tag (tag.json):

```
{
  "name": "tag",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "medias": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "media"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

**Solutions**

Now, I know I could do a query like this (using Angular SDK in my example, but the syntax is the same):

```
injector.get('Tag').find({
  'filter': {
    'include': 'medias',
    'where': {'id': <mytagid>}
  }
});
```

My problem with this approach is, that I receive 1 (`one`) `Tag` instance with attached `Media` instances. This disrupts why whole workflow as I deal only with `Media` instances.. i just want to *filter* by `Tag` id, not bother about `Tag` at all.

**Bottom line**

If I see the API explorer (`/explorer/`), the return value of `GET /api/tags/<myTagID>/medias` is exactly what I need - an array of `Media` objects - but how to query them exactly like this using the Angular SDK (lb_services)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem. One recommendation is to open the lb-services.js and try to find: /tags/:id/medias or something similar. Then you will find a comment like this: **// INTERNAL. Use Tags.medias() instead.** Or something similar. So that is the method that you should call. Do not call the "prototype$__get....." methods.

Then just call what it says there I suppose: Tag.medias({id:})

Other suggestions:

As you said in your description Media has many Tags. So why not use just

```
{
  "name": "media",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "hasMany",   <---------- hasMany
      "model": "tag",
      "foreignKey": "tagId" <---FK name
    }
  }
```

and 
for the tags just belongsTo as type.

```
{
  "name": "tag",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "medias": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "media",
      "foreignKey": "mediaId"  <---FK name
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

But really I don't think this is the problem because you said when you request `GET /api/tags/<myTagID>/medias` it returns what you want.

Then, in AngularJS you can use:

```
 Media.tags({id:<mediaId>})
```

for media/:id/tags

and for the other side try:

```
Tag.medias({id:<tagId>})


Tag.find({
       filter:{
          where:{mediaId: <mediaId>}     <----mediaId comes from FK name    
       }
   })
```

In this case both are persistent models there is no problems, I had permission problems when doing a similar thing with data that extends User type. But that is another story...

Hope this is helpful, I changed some stuff from a similar app that I am doing and hope not making so many errors when adapting to your code...

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed examples! I wasn't aware I can fetch associated instances (like a `Tag` `Media`s) using `Tag.medias({id:<tagId>})` - this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: You can also filter the results using:
`Tag.medias{
  id:<tagId>,
  filter:{
    where:{
    }
  }
}`